# Is using pattern names starting with "_" (underscore) for ignored results documented/encouraged/portable?

Tags: haskell, syntax, pattern-matching, wildcard, portability

Let's say I want to fork a thread within a `do`-notation block, but I don't care about the thread id. If I write

```
forkIO action
```

GHC issues warning

> Warning: A `do`-notation statement discarded a result of type `ThreadId`. Suppress this warning by saying
>
> ```
> _ <- forkOS action
> ```

This is a good idea as I want to show that the program is discarding some result. However, this way it won't be apparent what's being discarded. I could write

```
threadId <- forkIO action
```

but then we're hiding the fact that we won't use `threadId` anywhere, and GHC correctly warns

> Warning: Defined but not used: `threadId`

It seems that prepending underscore solves both problems:

```
_threadId <- forkIO action
```

**My questions are:** Is using variables starting with underscores legal according to Haskell's language specification? How portable is it? Is it documented somewhere? Is it encouraged for cases like this - to document that a result is being ignored?

Comment: It's legal, it's portable.  And I encourage it. :)

Comment: Having multiple wildcard identifiers for clarity is a good idea in my opinion, but if they're not going to warn about "Defined but not used" they shouldn't be *allowed* to be used!

Comment: @TomEllis Identifiers like `_thisOne` are allowed to be used. They're also allowed to be ignored.

Comment: @chunksOf50: Err yes, I forgot a "not".  Basically I don't think there should be any form of variable that doesn't warn about lack of use.  (But then I believe all sorts of heretical things, like incomplete pattern matches shouldn't be allowed).

Comment: Ah - you added "n't" to your should. I see your point. I can't help thinking of the way [Data.Lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens-template-2.1.3/docs/Data-Lens-Template.html) uses underscore record field names when generating lenses.

Comment: @chunksOf50: That's true.  I had forgotten about that.

Comment: You can also use `void $ forkIO action`, where `void :: Functor f => f a -> f ()` is defined in Control.Monad.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes. In [section 2.4 of the 2010 specification](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4), it says

> Underscore, `_`, is treated as a lowercase letter, and can occur wherever a lowercase letter can.

...so `_threadId` is a legal identifier according to the language spec which should be utterly portable.

> However, `_` all by itself is a reserved identifier, used as wild card in patterns.

...so you can't use `_` alone outside patterns, thus *can't* use that value.

> Compilers that offer warnings for unused identifiers are encouraged to suppress such warnings for identifiers beginning with underscore. This allows programmers to use `_foo` for a parameter that they expect to be unused.

So `_threadId` is an ordinary identifier which you *could* use elsewhere, but you shouldn't be warned if you throw it away.

(Exactly the same text is in the Haskell 98 report.)

---

Examples:

```
main = do
     _two <- return 2
     print _two       -- works
```

compiles and prints 2 according to the spec and

```
main = do
    _two <- return 2
    print 3           -- no warnings, but oops, didn't use _two
```

compiles without warning according to the spec, and

```
main = do
    _ <- return 2
    print _        -- syntax error: _ used as identifier
```

is a syntax error according to the spec.

Comment: is the `_` in `_ <- return 2` not a pattern? I think `... <- ...` _is_ a pattern match; if it fails, the `fail` of the `Monad` instance is called.

Comment: @GarethR Yes, `_` is a pattern, the syntax error is on the next line when you try to use it as an identifier. I've updated my answer to make it clearer, so thanks for the question.