# Get value of Maybe in Haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type

I am implementing a function `myFunction` which uses `anotherFunction`.

`anotherFunction` is an external function which cannot be modified. It returns a value of type `Maybe`.

`myFunction` is a recursive function that checks whether the value returned by another `myFunction` is a `Just` value or `Nothing`. If it's a `Nothing` then return `Nothing`, otherwise it will use the pure value returned by `myFunction` as an argument of `anotherFunction`.

Basically something like this:

```
--These cannot be modified

data A = B | F a

anotherFunction :: x -> Maybe x
--Something here

myFunction :: A -> Maybe x 

--These can be modified
myFunction (F a) = {- if (myFunction a == Nothing) 
                        then Nothing 
                        else anotherFunction (pure value of (myFunction a)) -}
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Use a case statement.

Comment: in Haskell normal functions (not constructors) normally start in lowercase.

Comment: Not only _do they normally_ start in lowercase, they _must_ start in lowercase to be allowed in Haskell. I edited the question accordingly. — — (In principle, an underscore is also allowed as the first character of a variable name, but don't do that – [the underscore has a special meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282515/is-using-pattern-names-starting-with-underscore-for-ignored-results-docume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match on the value returned from `MyFunction` using `case`:

```
case (myFunction a) of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just x -> anotherFunction x
```

however a more concise method is to use `>>=`:

```
(>>=) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
myFunction (f a) = (myFunction a) >>= anotherFunction
```

or you can use `do` notation:

```
myFunction (f a) = do
  x <- myFunction a
  anotherFunction x
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use `==` unless you have the constraint `Eq a => Maybe a` in the signature. The best way to do this type of thing is to use a `case` statement:

```
case m of
    Just x -> anotherFunction x
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

This pattern is so common for `Maybe` that it forms the `Monad` instance for `Maybe`, giving you the functions `return x = Just x` and `f >>= x = case x of Just a -> f a; Nothing -> Nothing`.

Comment: Don't call it `maybe`. That's the name of a function in the Prelude.

Comment: @Zeta Thank you, changed.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have `f` and `g` that both produce values wrapped into type `Maybe` (`Just 3`, `Just "three"`, `Nothing`). You can compose the two like:

```
import Control.Monad

f :: a -> Maybe b -- suppose these two are signatures of the given two functions
g :: b -> Maybe c

h :: a -> Maybe c -- this is the way you pass values from one
h = f >=> g       -- to the other and bail out when you see Nothing
```

I have used convenient names for the types `a`, `b`, and `c` to make the composition more clear, but notice that the types are not constraint and `a` in one signature has nothing to do with `a` in another signature, the actual type is decided when the two functions are used in concrete context.

As you don't seem to put any constraint on what `a` in `F a` constructor is, I suppose you want it to be possibly different from `A`. In that case the function `myFunction` cannot have type `A -> ...` because you are trying to pass `a` as the argument.